# Super Search search between two channels

Tags: solspace, supersearch

Here writing again because I do not know how to solve a problem.

I'm using Super Search and trying to search inside a channel using a keywords from other channel:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel-1" limit="1"}

    {exp:super_search:results channel="channel-2" search="keywords={channel-1-custom-field}"}
        {title}</br>
        {channel-2-custom-field}
    {/exp:super_search:results}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

`{super_search_total_results}` works and gets the number of results.
I want to know how to get `{channel-2-custom-field}` and `{title}` from channel 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since Super Search uses the same Library as the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag pair, they share similar variable names. The outer `{exp:channel:entries}` tag pair would parse first, followed by the inner `{exp:super_search:results}` tag. This would be why `{title}`, for example, parses to the outer `{exp:channel:entries}` value.

In other words, the issue is similar to nesting two `{exp:channel:entries}` tag pairs inside each other: you can't do that, or at least EE won't parse correctly.

One way around this is to place the `{exp:super_search:results}` code in an embed tag (and pass your `{channel-1-custom-field}` variable in the embed). This avoids parsing order issues and variable clashes.